# Preloader with sprite animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, css

I'm fairly new to JS. Took a few lynda courses, but I can't wrap my head around creating a sprite preloader (animated). Googled a lot, searched through stackoverflow, came close to what I want, but didn`t land it. To the point, I have this logo I created (already set it up as a sprite), so I want the sprite to animate according to the percentage of loaded files.

Ex. on 0%-15% I'll have the first one, second one between 15% and 30% and so on till the last, point in which I`ll set the div to visiblity:hidden, like so :

**HTML**

```
<div id="preloader">
```

**CSS**

```
#preloader {
margin: 0-auto;
width: 450px;
height: 400px;
background-color: #282727;
background-image: url(http://roprojects.net/preloader/sprite.PNG)
}
```

**JS** not sure, sorry if the below written seems dumb.

```
// var percent = Something that would get the numeric progress of the page load;
$( window ).load(function() {
// example of first animation. And I don't even know how I should be going on from here.
// Maybe a for statement, some sort of a loop, was even thinking conditionals. 
// Maybe a case/switch
// if (percent > 15 && percent <= 30) {below } 
  $('#preloader').css('backgroundPosition', '0 -400px');
});
// But ultimately that would require it to ..update itself (loop, I guess?)
```

This is my first post, thank you for your time and patience. Any external reference is also welcomed, not expecting you to write it for me. Again, thank you a **lot**!

**edit** the sprite itself. http://roprojects.net/preloader/sprite.PNG

**edit** #2 I've realised I should also give an end-result example of the preloader, so here it is : http://www.fk-agency.com/ . So I realised by looking through the js

```
 if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
 {
  var pos = navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE");
  var ver = navigator.appVersion.substr(pos,8);
  if((ver == "MSIE 6.0") || (ver == "MSIE 7.0")) { var oldie = true}
}     
    if(oldie != true){
    $(window).load(function() { 
        setTimeout(function(){
        $("#loading").fadeOut(function() { 
            $("#container").fadeIn(1500) 
        })
        },300);
    })
    }
```

So what I'm getting from this is that we do a browsercheck and if everything's working out nice, once the page loads, the preloader div fades out and the main page comes in. But still, clueless towards how that sprite gets filled. (I'm assuming that it's just two images, the other completing from left to right.) Still have to figure out how to bind the css property changes to the numerical page load process itself. ...The quest continues.

Comment: Ok just finally got home, now I have time to think about the answer. The browsercheck you posted from this other website is not something you should take as an example, you almost always want to check for features you want to use, not for browsers, and first you make it work on the few browser(s) you like and can check and debug on and ignore all others for a while.

Comment: Welcome home! I'm looking and looking and spilling my eyes out.  I'm still making attempts while looking at jquery events triggers at the same time, maybe I'll get some results with that.

Comment: But from what @user3549636 posted before, I at least got some idea over how to set 'said' trigger. Frames are not the way to go, as the speed is stable (and tough it can be random numbered), I need it to load accordingly with the elements. I`m thinking like this : if I can set the objects I want to load as an array, and if I have a loop that constantly checks if they're loaded, I can asign a certain sprite depending on the total number of elements loaded. Say 150 elements to load , if elLoaded >elToLoad/4 => change property of div to -400px (sprite 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `i++` with whatever your percentage code is.
JS:

```
var i = 1;
setInterval(function () {
    if (i < 318) {
        i++;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("transparentImg").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("percentage").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("background").style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById("percentage").style.width = i + "px";
}, 100);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="background"><div/>
<div id="percentage"><div/>
<img id="transparentImg" src="http://vividvid.tk/images/imageedit_4_9586029984.gif"/>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  background-color: black;
}
#percentage{
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  width:320px;
  height:80px;
  margin-left:-150px;
  left:47%;
  margin-top:-40px;
  top:50%;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
}
#background{
  background-color: rgb(100,100,100);
  width:320px;
  height:80px;
  margin-left:-150px;
  left:50%;
  margin-top:-40px;
  top:50%;
  position:absolute
}
#transparentImg{
  width:320px;
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to also look this up and stuff, I first set up a horizontal scroll to see how it manifests and I know for sure it's not what I need. The animation looks glitchy, like a gif of some sort. What I want to do is load parts of the sprite directly proprtional to percentage of page loaded. I've just flipped the image for a preview here http://roprojects.net/preloader/test2.html . So yeah, unfortunately that doesn't work for me. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: @2easy yeah sorry my bad, but looking at the example you've given i don;t think its possible with colours... if you want i can post a one-colour version though

Comment: +1 after reading this solution I have to admit it's quite sophisticated. Welcome to Stackoverflow (both of you), your coding style is going to improve drastically if you stay for a while :)

But yeah that's what an animation can look like.

Comment: @user3549636 oh yeah I do like this solution more, it's much clearer and shorter, you might want to update your post with the new code. Your old code had some...exotic...ways of doing things (which I could be a dick and point out if you want :)

Comment: @Winchestro haha yeah ok.

Comment: @user3549636 Despite weird naming (always pick descriptive names telling you the purpose anything you name as clearly and short as possible) this version already looks pretty good. (You also could clean up the css and remove things that are not required for a solution). The loading is of course simulated here, in the final implementation you would actually check for the resources loaded, but I think 2easy already got that covered :)

Comment: I've read your edits, but they've been of course declined since that's what comments are for :) But I made a lil' fiddle as inspiration for what kind of effects are super easy to make and learn to make with canvas.

Answer (score 0):

if you check the Performance API `window.performance` you will find all the data you need to power your loading graphics.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Navigation_timing

On the second thought, starting with the performance API might be an overkill if you just started out with JS.

To give you an overview about the the simpler tools at your disposal:

- `requestAnimationFrame(yourFunction)` this function will take your function and execute it efficiently if it makes sense (user is looking at your tab, computer can actually render it etc) If you put it anywhere inside a function and let it call **itself** this way, you have an efficient animation loop allowing you to smoothly animate your image.
- Event Listeners. You already use one, your current code is executed when the document is loaded. But you can of course also add a load event on every single resource you load and let it update something in your animation.

  There are tons of event listeners, allowing you to listen to almost
  everything and do the proper updates, so you don't have to check all
  the time if something happened. If you just update a single counter
  by 1 every time a resource loaded and divide it by the total amount
  of resources you have your percentage.
- Canvas: I do like your sprite, and I have no doubt it can be animated with css, but if you want to have a lot of control about special effects, or even generate your own images and animate them or do things to sprites, like changing colors, transforming, blending, drawing on them, the canvas will be something you might want to befriend.

Just had fun making a tiny fiddle of how I'd make a loading animation (canvas based), if you want inspiration http://jsfiddle.net/bbVTB/2/

Unless your loading time is expected to be longer than a bunch of seconds I wouldn't even bother making it somehow visualising actual loading progress but rather distract the user and give him a feeling of short- and long term progress, that's why there is this silly spinning and at the same time the slow "weaving" of something, the user would be curious about what it becomes just long enough for the loading to finish.

I think it may even be a mistake to actually show the loading time unless it's taking so long people lose patience and leave. It's like staring at a clock, waiting for time to pass. Why not instead make the user stare on something at least a bit enjoyable? but that's not really programming related, but a design decision.

Comment: thank you. I'll go take a look at the docs and see if I can put something together. I'll post an edit when I'm done. Again, thank you.

Comment: my pleasure, i'm currently reading your question again and see a few more points to adress, because i feel like my answer is incridibly short and incomplete as it is

Comment: I'm still in the trenches with the documentation there, but I thought maybe it'll help if I gave an example of the end-result : http://www.fk-agency.com/ . Their preloader is the example. I'm currently looking at their javascript to get a better idea and maybe just comprehend more. I'll edit the original post to spare you of looking through bunches of scripts in the head tags.